# Issue in display of barchart with latest ioscharts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I updated ios-charts to the latest code after 2 months. I see lot of difference when I run the code.

This is before updating the library:

[image]

After updating:

[image]

Here's the code that generates the chart:

```
    chart.infoTextColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        chart.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        chart.descriptionText = ""
        chart.noDataText = "Loading..."
        chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        chart.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true

        chart.legend.position = .BelowChartCenter;
        chart.legend.form = .Circle;
        chart.legend.formSize = 10.0;
        chart.legend.formToTextSpace = 10.0;
        chart.legend.xEntrySpace = 4.0;
        chart.legend.yEntrySpace = 2.0
        chart.legend.stackSpace = 5.0
        chart.legend.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        chart.xAxis.gridColor = UIColor.blueColor()
//        chart.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        chart.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        chart.borderColor = UIColor.redColor()

//        chart.xAxis.labelHeight = 18
//        chart.xAxis.labelWidth = 18
        chart.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom;
        chart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false;

        chart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false;

        //zooming..
        chart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        chart.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        chart.scaleXEnabled = false
        chart.scaleYEnabled = false

        //new..
        chart.leftAxis.labelPosition = .InsideChart
chartDataSet.barSpace = 0.38
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: This screen shot was just now with old as well as updated code. I am passing same information for both the graph.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code? You're going to need to post your setting chart function along with the data entries, data set, etc.

Comment: why it's on hold? I can confirm it's reproducible, and can be solved by setting customAxisMin = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest release has deprecated `startAtZeroEnabled`, which seems is your case.

Please try set `customAxisMin` to get the expcted range. e.g. `customAxisMin = 0`

remember to set it before calling `chartView.data = yourData`, or you need to specificly call `chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks, now the graph is working fine. I saw the answer just.

Comment: Is there any way to set the width of each bar?

Comment: check out barSpace, and don't ask irrelevant question in one thread